# Analogue switch TS3A475 does the direction matter?

Tags: bidirectional, analog-switch

Does the "direction" of the signal matter?

[image]

signal is 1/3Vcc to 2/3Vcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. But you need to make sure that the voltage is within the range specified in the datasheet (usually it must be between the supply rails of the switch), and also the switch has a non-zero resistance *and* a maximum allowed current through it. The switch resistance will be highly dependent on *both* temperature and voltage, so have to make sure that such variations won't unacceptably affect the performance of your entire system.

Comment: Thank you. Current is in in range 1-5mA so the temperature is not changing (Vcc 3.3V)

Comment: *Current is in in range 1-5mA so the temperature is not changing* If anything, if the current varies then the temperature will be changing since you're heating the switch up. The temperature will be also affected by the environmental conditions. Calculate the power dissipation in the switch for 1mA and 5mA, then use the thermal model of the chip (its parameters are given in the thermal specs in the datasheet) to calculate the junction temperature at those two currents. Then superpose the environmental changes on top of changes due to current variation.

Comment: Once you got junction temperature extremes, you can verify that you won't be exceeding the limits the chip can operate at, and you can then also derive roughly what will be the change in resistance - based on plots or equations given in the datasheet, or using some general mosfet transistor model to get an idea at least of the order of magnitude of change.